# Github activity feed urls dont include domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, feedjira

I want to display a user's activity feed in an rails application. I am using feedjira.

```
2.2.4 :006 > xml_feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_raw "https://github.com/prasadsurase.atom"
2.2.4 :006 > github_feed = Feedjira::Feed.parse xml_feed
2.2.4 :006 > github_feed.entries.first.content
=> "<!-- pull_request -->\n<svg aria-label=\"Pull request\" class=\"octicon octicon-git-pull-request dashboard-event-icon\" height=\"32\" role=\"img\" version=\"1.1\" viewBox=\"0 0 12 16\" width=\"24\"><path d=\"M11 11.28V5c-.03-.78-.34-1.47-.94-2.06C9.46 2.35 8.78 2.03 8 2H7V0L4 3l3 3V4h1c.27.02.48.11.69.31.21.2.3.42.31.69v6.28A1.993 1.993 0 0 0 10 15a1.993 1.993 0 0 0 1-3.72zm-1 2.92c-.66 0-1.2-.55-1.2-1.2 0-.65.55-1.2 1.2-1.2.65 0 1.2.55 1.2 1.2 0 .65-.55 1.2-1.2 1.2zM4 3c0-1.11-.89-2-2-2a1.993 1.993 0 0 0-1 3.72v6.56A1.993 1.993 0 0 0 2 15a1.993 1.993 0 0 0 1-3.72V4.72c.59-.34 1-.98 1-1.72zm-.8 10c0 .66-.55 1.2-1.2 1.2-.65 0-1.2-.55-1.2-1.2 0-.65.55-1.2 1.2-1.2.65 0 1.2.55 1.2 1.2zM2 4.2C1.34 4.2.8 3.65.8 3c0-.65.55-1.2 1.2-1.2.65 0 1.2.55 1.2 1.2 0 .65-.55 1.2-1.2 1.2z\"></path></svg>\n\n<div class=\"time\">\n  <relative-time datetime=\"2016-09-23T07:30:24Z\">Sep 23, 2016</relative-time>\n</div>\n\n<div class=\"title\">\n  <a href=\"/prasadsurase\" data-ga-click=\"News feed, event click, Event click type:PullRequestEvent target:actor\">prasadsurase</a> opened pull request <a href=\"/joshsoftware/code-curiosity/pull/136\" data-ga-click=\"News feed, event click, Event click type:PullRequestEvent target:pull\">joshsoftware/code-curiosity#136</a>\n</div>\n\n<div class=\"details\">\n  <a href=\"/prasadsurase\"><img alt=\"@prasadsurase\" class=\"gravatar\" height=\"30\" src=\"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/562052?v=3&amp;s=60\" width=\"30\" /></a>\n  <div class=\"message\">\n    <blockquote>Fixed controller method scopes. Removed unwanted routes.</blockquote>\n      <div class=\"pull-info\">\n        <svg aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"octicon octicon-git-commit\" height=\"16\" version=\"1.1\" viewBox=\"0 0 14 16\" width=\"14\"><path d=\"M10.86 7c-.45-1.72-2-3-3.86-3-1.86 0-3.41 1.28-3.86 3H0v2h3.14c.45 1.72 2 3 3.86 3 1.86 0 3.41-1.28 3.86-3H14V7h-3.14zM7 10.2c-1.22 0-2.2-.98-2.2-2.2 0-1.22.98-2.2 2.2-2.2 1.22 0 2.2.98 2.2 2.2 0 1.22-.98 2.2-2.2 2.2z\"></path></svg>\n        <em>1</em> commit with\n        <em>34</em> additions and\n        <em>31</em> deletions\n      </div>\n  </div>\n</div>\n"
```

when rendering the **content** for every **entry** from **github_feed.entries** in haml as **raw**, the links do not contain the domain **https://github.com/** but contain only the path. This causes problem as such that the rendered links on the UI contain the app domain and not github. How do we fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since github atom feeds provides the content with relative url's you might want to replace them with absolute references.

This could be done with

```
gsub( %r{<a href=\"/},'<a href="https://github.com/')
```

And thus replace your:

```
2.2.4 :006 > github_feed.entries.first.content
```

with

```
2.2.4 :006 > github_feed.entries.first.content.gsub( %r{<a href=\"/},'<a href="https://github.com/')
=> "<!-- pull_request_review_comment -->\n<svg aria-label=\"Review pull request comment\" class=\"octicon octicon-comment-discussion dashboard-event-icon\" height=\"32\" role=\"img\" version=\"1.1\" viewBox=\"0 0 16 16\" width=\"32\"><path d=\"M15 1H6c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v2H1c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v6c0 .55.45 1 1 1h1v3l3-3h4c.55 0 1-.45 1-1V9h1l3 3V9h1c.55 0 1-.45 1-1V2c0-.55-.45-1-1-1zM9 11H4.5L3 12.5V11H1V5h4v3c0 .55.45 1 1 1h3v2zm6-3h-2v1.5L11.5 8H6V2h9v6z\"></path></svg>\n\n<div class=\"time\">\n  <relative-time datetime=\"2016-09-28T03:21:31Z\">Sep 28, 2016</relative-time>\n</div>\n\n<div class=\"title\">\n  <a href=\"https://github.com/prasadsurase\" data-ga-click=\"News feed, event click, Event click type:PullRequestReviewCommentEvent target:actor\">prasadsurase</a> commented on pull request <a href=\"https://github.com/joshsoftware/code-curiosity/pull/137#discussion_r80837476\" data-ga-click=\"News feed, event click, Event click type:PullRequestReviewCommentEvent target:pull-comment\">joshsoftware/code-curiosity#137</a>\n</div>\n\n<div class=\"details\">\n  <a href=\"https://github.com/prasadsurase\"><img alt=\"@prasadsurase\" class=\"gravatar\" height=\"30\" src=\"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/562052?v=3&amp;s=60\" width=\"30\" /></a>\n  <div class=\"message markdown-body\">\n    <blockquote>\n      <p><a href=\"https://github.com/BandanaPandey\" class=\"user-mention\">@BandanaPandey</a> Same here.</p>\n    </blockquote>\n  </div>\n</div>\n"
```